# Blazor MAUI + WEB application with MongoDB on azure AKS

Tags: .net, azure, blazor, asp.net-identity, azure-aks

I'm starting a new SAAS project application on Blazor.

I have some experience with blazor and azure but It's the first time I have to design a complex architecture and a SAAS application, I would like to take some advices here.

It's a SAAS application and I would like to use the "multi instance" architecture as bellow :
[image: SAAS Architecture]

The technologies I think I will use :

Front : Blazor MAUI (WEB, IOS, Android, Windows)
Back : ASP .NET API
Database : Mongo DB (non relationnal Database)
Hosting : Microsoft Azure
DevOps - CI/CD pipeline : Azure DevOps (https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/products/devops)

Don't hesitate to give some advice on the technologies I chosed. I'm very familiar with blazor and I think It's the easiest way to have a multi platform application (and in addiction, I HATE javascript haha. I'm a .NET developer)

I have few questions :

- Do you think this architecture is doable in microsoft azure infrastructure ? Using the AKS and hosted Mongo databases on Azure for each clients ? (+ 1 global Database for the project management)
- I'm hesitating between cosmos DB and MongoDB Atlas, I'm not sure to understand the practicals differences between these two. I could also include the Mongo DB in the AKS for each clients, but I'm wondering about the backup and the reliability of data. I think cosmos DB or MongoDB Atlas are ready to use with all backuping and security already in place, but maybe I'm wrong and It's not that hard to use It.
- I'm still hesitating between Mongo DB and Azure Table, because I also have experience with Azure Tables. But I'm wondering if we can use It as a full database for an application.
- I know mongo is not recomended for using authentification with Identity Framework, but do you think It can be a good idea ? I'm not that good in SQL and relationnal DB but I have experience with mongo.
- I have few knoledge on kubernetes and docker but very minimal, I can use them but to implement a full infrastructure I miss some skills, do you have any recomendations, documentations or tutorials that could help me ?
- Same on Azure devops, I don't have many skills but I need the ability to deploy easily on different environment and easily create new instance (Web server + Back + Mongo DB) for each environment
- I'm wondering if I really need an ASP.NET back end between my blazor and my database, because blazor is also a self hosted ASP.NET core project. What do you think ? Having the front interact with the database directly for each client is a good idea ?

Thank in advance for your anwsers.